# Can I have a single git Azure Repo?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

My goal is to use either a single or multiple Azure Repos without Azure DevOps that work kind of a strange?

For example, in AWS you can use only [CodeCommit](https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/) to store your source. Also. you have independent [CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/), CodeBuild, and so on.

**My Question:** Are there any independent services like this in AWS?

It seems that there are many usable resources in this DevOps tool.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. If you want *just* a repo, maybe just grant repo access to people, and don't grant access to anything else? Or just ignore unused features?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "work kind of a strange?" Are you saying "Would it be strange to do this?" Or are you saying "I have some unusual requirements"? If the latter, what are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.  Unlike AWS , CodeCommit  is an independent service.

Azure DevOps Services provides development collaboration tools including high-performance build/release pipelines, free private Git repositories, configurable Kanban boards, and extensive automated and cloud-based load testing.

In other words, Azure DevOps combine CodeDeploy ,CodeCommit ,CodePipeline ,CodeBuild services  in AWS together and even more such as test, report...  It's not just a source control management tool. With using Azure DevOps, it can help you manage the whole application lifecycle.

Besides, you could find AWS to Azure services comparison [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/aws-professional/services#devops-and-application-monitoring):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Git Repo and Pipelines are part of Azure DevOps. You need to create a project in DevOps in which you can have one or multiple Git repositories, and one or multiple pipeline per repository. So you can have for each git repo multiple pipelines.

Also, when creating a new project in Azure DevOps, you choose which features you want to have (repo, tests, pipelines, etc.). So, you can make it simple and add only the necessary features.

The other option is to use GitHub and install Azure pipelines from the [marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace/azure-pipelines).

Here is a tutorial how to do that: [Continuous Builds with your GitHub projects using Azure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vlBuNM6Wzic).

Comment: This get a much of complex for me.
Why I should spend time to learn new kind of services such as DevOps Projects/Starter - A app service going to run - complete madnes just for one SCM.
Azure did great job with independent Container Registry. If they have separated their Artefacts, Repo and Pipelines will be much better.
ps.
I DONT WANT TO SPEND MONEY AND TIME - this is the reason not to go in Marketplace / VM's /SVC an so on.
Thanks Mohamed

Comment: You can ask Microsoft that question using azure user voice to report your feedback. Meanwhile, the second solution with GitHub is straight forward and I believe it has the same level of complexity of AWS.